# How to let CMake put .lib files inside the build folder

Tags: c++, cmake, visual-studio-2019

I have a C++-project with a structure like this:

```
├─examples
│  ├─main.cpp
│  └─CMakeLists.txt
├─unittests
│    ├─main.cpp
│    ├─other source files
│    └─CMakeLists.txt
├─actualLib // static library
│    ├─source files
│    └─CMakeLists.txt
├─CMakeLists.txt // top-level CMakeLists file
├─build // build folder created by CMake
├─x64 // folder created by CMake that contains .pdb, .lib and .exe files
```

The top-level CMakeLists.txt is including the subdirectory files via:

```
add_subdirectory(actualLib ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/actualLib)
add_subdirectory(examples ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/examples)
add_subdirectory(unittests ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/unittests)
```

Now, when I want to build the project/solution in Release mode, I use:

```
cmake -S "C:\actualLib\actualLib" -B "build" -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -A "x64"
cmake --build "build" --config Release
```

Until here everything is fine. The object files, intermediate cmake files, project and solution files and all the stuff are put inside the newly created "build" folder in the directory of the top-level CMakeLists.txt. But what drives me crazy is that, no matter what I try, the .lib file from the "actualLib" project and the .exe files from the "examples" and "unittests" projects are put in a separate, also newly created "x64" folder in the same directory. But I want those files also being put inside the "build" folder, each in a separate subfolder based on the project.

What I tried so far:

Setting the library, runtime and archive directories globally (inside the top-level file):

```
set (CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})
set (CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})
set (CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})
```

Setting those properties target based, e. g. inside the "actualLib" CMakeLists.text file:

```
set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES
    RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/actualLib/bin
    LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/actualLib/lib
    ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/actualLib/lib
)
```

I tried also setting the paths relative to the `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}` or `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}`, but it didn't change anything. Still, the "x64" folder is created for the .lib/.exe files. For me as a CMake rookie, this seems to be a special Visual Studio problem, because the solutions I mentioned above seem to be working for everybody else. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: May I ask you why do you want to do it? i.e., What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I use VS and CMake. Using `SET(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})` in the top-level CMake puts all .exe, .pdb, and .dll's into the same folder. `.lib` files aren't really meant to be put there though. The `CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` is what you want for that, if you have the project setup correctly. See here: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html#archive-output-artifacts

Comment: @ChrisMM But that is exactly what I'm doing in my top-level CMakeLists.txt file, setting CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY, CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY and CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY to ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}, but the corresponding files are still put inside the "x64" folder instead. Where does this "x64" comes from, I mean there must be a setting to specify e. g. the name of this folder and maybe also the destination of it, but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: @gordan.sikic Maybe thats just a personal preference, but I like all the build artifacts to be in the same base folder. Ideally, I would end up with something like "build -> actualLib -> lib -> actualLib.lib" and "build -> actualLib -> bin -> objFiles".

Comment: From the CMake docs: _Multi-configuration generators (Visual Studio, Xcode, Ninja Multi-Config) append a per-configuration subdirectory to the specified directory unless a generator expression is used._

Comment: In that case, how do you plan to organize multiple build types, and possible clashes between them?

Comment: @gordan.sikic Ok, I think I was not clear enough. Of course I don't want every file to be just thrown into the said folder. For example, currently, the path to the object files (Release mode) of the "actualLib" project looks like this:

C:\...\build\actualLib\actualLib.dir\Release

And what I want is to split the "Release" folder again in two sub-folders, one called "lib" with the "autolib.lib" file and one called "bin" with all the object files, which currently are already inside "../Release". This way, everything would still be well organized, but also in the same base folder "build".

Comment: I'd question _why_ you want to do this. Build systems and IDEs handle these details because they're not relevant... In all my years of development, I've never needed to look at those folders... Anyway,  you can look at VS's settings though, I think that's the intermediate directory. See how it's set in VS, then set the appropriate property in Cmake.